# Character group

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Each character f of G is constant over the classes of conjugated elements of the group G. Does this mean that:
$f(hgh ^{-1} )=f(g)$, $g,h \in G$ ?

If so, I'm having trouble proving it.  I define a character to be such that $f(ab)=f(a)f(b)$…but what's next?  Please help in the proof.

Comment: Did you try it? What is your definition of a character, can you start from there?

Answer (score 2):

A character of a group over a field $K$ is a group homomorphism 
$$ \psi : G \to K^\times $$
where $K^\times = K \smallsetminus \{0\}$ is the multiplicative group of $K$. Since it is homomorphism then for every $g,h \in G$ we have
$$ \psi(g \cdot h) = \psi(g) \cdot \psi(h) \quad \mbox{ and } \quad \psi(g^{-1}) = (\psi(g))^{-1} $$
so
$$ \psi(h g h^{-1}) = \psi(h)\psi(g)\psi(h^{-1}) = \psi(h)\psi(g)\psi(h)^{-1} = \psi(h)\psi(h)^{-1}\psi(g) = \psi(g) $$
since $K^\times$ is abelian, and $\operatorname{Im} \psi \subset K^\times$.

(Note that you have a mistake in your question.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's correct. The statement follows from $\mathrm{tr}(fgf^{-1})=\mathrm{tr}(g)$, which in turns is a special case of $\mathrm{tr}(fg)=\mathrm{tr}(gf)$.

Comment: Should be f(hgh^-1)=f(g) ?

Comment: $f$ and $g$ are invertible linear maps.

Comment: Oh yes, it's a typo.

Answer (score -1):

Each character $f$ of the group $G$ is constant on the classes of conjugated elements of the group $G$.

$a$, $b$ belonging to $G$ are coupled <=> exists $g$ belonging to $G$ such that $a = gbg ^ {-1}$.

So it should be $f (a) = f (b)$, so $f (gbg ^ {-1}) = f (b)$, right?